# Append to value attribute on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I am trying to make an input modify each time I click on a button. Kind of like a calculator. The  will start at 0. When I click on the button "7" it will change its value to **7**, when I click on "4" it will change to **74**. Basically like a calculator.

I made this code that does modify the *value* of the input, however I can't seem to find how I can ***append*** more values to that values. Here is my code. Could someone help me?

```
<input class="normal-input" type="number" step="0.01"> <!-- Value is NULL-->
<button value="7" class="my-buttons" type="button"> 7 </button> <!--Button to change the value of the input-->

 $('.my-buttons').click(function(){
     $(".normal-input").attr("value", $(this).attr('value'));
 }); <!-- The actual function. -->
```

As you can see the function completely replaces the previous value for the new one. I want it to append the values like in a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try doing this:

- Initialize value to zero
- whenever click is called, multiply the current value by 10, and add the button value to it.
- and you can remove the step attribute as per the use case.

Answer (score 0):

In this function:

```
$(".normal-input").attr("value", $(this).attr('value'));
```

The second parameter is the value to set:

```
$(this).attr('value')
```

You need to have this as a combination of the previous value and the new value:

```
$(".normal-input").attr('value') + '' + $(this).attr('value')
```

The blank string is to make sure the final result is a string, not the addition of 2 numbers.

If you would like to convert it to a number, you can use parseInt():

```
const combinedNumber = $(".normal-input").attr('value') + '' + $(this).attr('value')
const intNumber = parseInt(combinedNumber)
```

The final code could look something like:

```
<input class="normal-input" type="number" step="0.01"> <!-- Value is NULL-->
<button value="7" class="my-buttons" type="button"> 7 </button> <!--Button to change the value of the input-->



$('.my-buttons').click(function(){

    const existingValue = $(".normal-input").attr('value')
    const newValue = $(this).attr('value'
    const combinedValue = parseInt(existingValue + '' + newValue)
    $(".normal-input").attr("value", combinedValue);

 }); <!-- The actual function. -->
```

Comment: Hello! I tried using this one but it does not quite work. I also modified it to this: 
$(".normal-input").attr('value',  'value' + $(this).attr('value'));
Do you know what could happen?

Comment: I have edited the response to give a complete solution - please let me know if that works better

Answer (score 0):

You just need to *concat* both the actual value and the value of button which is clicked to get required values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.my-buttons').click(function() {
  var value = $(".normal-input").val()
  var clicked_button = $(this).attr('value')
  //use val and combined both value
  $(".normal-input").val(value + "" + clicked_button);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="normal-input" type="number">
<button value="7" class="my-buttons" type="button"> 7 </button>
<button value="10" class="my-buttons" type="button"> 10 </button>
<button value="6" class="my-buttons" type="button"> 6 </button>
```